# What does GetTickCount() actually measure?

Tags: winapi

I want to know what does the Windows API [`GetTickCount()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) actually measure? Does it measure the time from the instant the power button of the system is pressed? Does it measure the time taken by bootloaders or BIOS to load as well?
I am trying to measure the boot time on Windows 7.

Comment: `GetTickCount` of what system???? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GetTickCount

Comment: I assume that this is Windows, so this might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Get a stop watch and work it out for yourself. It's trivially easy to do the experiment.

Comment: 'Boot time' what is that?  Power on is easy to signal, either with a hardware timer truggered by the power supply output or by pushing the 'start' button on @DavidHeffernan stopwatch at the same time as pushing the power button.  When boot up is completed is more difficult to define, and measure.

Comment: Seeing as Windows is not even running at the time the power button is pressed, it would be difficult for Windows to account for that. If you are measuring boot time from power-on, you need to use a stopwatch.

Answer (score 16):

You should not treat it as measuring the time "since" anything. Use it only as a relative clock source. In other words, call `GetTickCount` once, then do something, then call it again, then subtract. Do not use the absolute value of the tick count.

The precise start time is unspecified, and on debugging builds of Windows, the "boot time" is artificially set to 49.7 days in the past in order to expose timer rollover bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Since [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't specify, you can only assume that the precise moment during startup is not really defined, and it could work differently on different versions of Windows. But consider that with virtualization and emulation, "since the power button was pushed" would be meaningless. The best consistent definition you could hope for would be the moment that Windows starts serving interrupts -- the earliest moment that the system clock is available.

Answer (score 0):

GetTickCount() is mainly meant for measuring *short* time *intervals*. The zero point of GTC is basically undefined.

Also, from what I've seen, GTC matches very closely the value of `QueryPerformanceCounter() * 1000 / QueryPerformanceFrequency()`, so I'm guessing this is how it's implemented on the machines that support QPC and QPF.

Now, there are two common options for determining Windows uptime.

1. Query the `\\.\System\System Up Time` performance counter. Beware of the [caveats on non-English boxes](http://www.hardtoc.com/archives/88). Also, based on my testing, this method simply doesn't work under Wow64, with `PdhCollectQueryData` returning NO_DATA.
2. Run a WMI query for `LastBootUpTime` value from `Win32_OperatingSystem table`. This is *heavy*, so you'd typically want to get it and cache it. It's also fragile as WMI can break in mysterious ways. Lastly, I saw standard `systeminfo` utility that is based on WMI return invalid boot time, which was off by more than 1 day.

Another option is to use `GetSystemTimes` to get idle/kernel/user times of all CPUs, tally them up, divide by the CPU count and take that as an approximation of the uptime. Having experimented with this, I find it rather imprecise and yielding higher than normal uptime.

So, all in all, there is not simple and lightweight way to determine boot- or uptime on Windows. Nothing comparable to reading `/proc/uptime` on *nix. Surprise, surprise.